# How to filter common users from multiple belongstomany relationship pivot tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot, laravel-blade, has-and-belongs-to-many, laravel-controller

[There are table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0zaF.png)
Sellers table are main table. Services and Areas tables can contain multiple services and areas for spacific Seller. For this I use seller_services and sellerable Pivot table belongsToMany() relationship to access services and areas.

```
In Seller Model
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Service');
    }

    public function areas()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Area', 'sellerable');
    }


In Service Model
    public function sellers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Seller');
    }

In Area Model
    public function sellers()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Seller', 'sellerable');
    }
```

**Now the problem is....
If I request any service and any area then I want to access those Seller who have those requested services and area. And get all seller who matched this both request.
**

I try those....

```
        $service_name = Service::where('slug', $request->service)->first();

        $area = Area::findOrFail($request->area);
        
        $sellers = $service_name->sellers;

        $sellers = $area->sellers;
```

In Blade

```
    @if ($sellers)
        @foreach ($sellers as $seller)
            {{$seller->name}}
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

And Also Try....

```
@if ($service_name)
    @foreach ($service_name->sellers and $area_name->sellers as $seller)
         {{$seller->name}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

but it this way we can't access sellers who has both request. I need to access sellers where service and area will match this seller records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

```
class Seller extends Model
{

    public function sellerServiceAreas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SellerServiceArea::class);
    }

   
}

class Service extends Model
{


    public function sellerServiceAreas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SellerServiceArea::class);
    }

    
}

class Area extends Model
{


    public function sellerServiceAreas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SellerServiceArea::class);
    }

}

class SellerServiceArea extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['seller_id', 'service_id', 'area_id', 'price'];

    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Seller::class);
    }

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }
}
```

> And then get the result using :

```
In Controller
$service = Service::where('name', 'Service Name')->first();
$area = Area::where('name', 'Area Name')->first();

$sellers = Seller::whereHas('sellerServiceAreas', function ($query) use 
($service, $area) {
$query->where('service_id', $service->id)->where('area_id', $area->id);
 })->get();
```